# Interfacing with a Futaba RC controller using c++ and ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, joystick, remote-control

So I am hoping to use a Futaba remote controller (specifically the Futaba 7c 2.4ghz) for a c++ + OpenGL simulator that I wrote.

Are there Ubuntu packages available to assist with this? I am okay with buying the USB cable to connect the controller to the computer,  but then I need a c/c++ SDK to allow the controller to communicate with my program.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Futaba and all other controllers send/receive PPM signals. You need a device (USB device for example) which is capable of receiving PPM signals.

For example this device:
http://www.mftech.de/usb-interface_en.htm

Also you can go "hackish" way
Just like this:
http://wiki.neuronrobotics.com/PPM_Reader_Channel
and
http://diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/705844:BlogPost:38393

You can use an Arudino or ArduPilot board to receive signals from controller, then send it with Serial port to USB converter to PC for processing.

I remember I've done something similar to this with a basic Arduino. If I recall correctly, I had a signal cable connected from Futaba's RC receiver part to Arduino and I was able to receive PPM signals. Something like this: https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/348

Also you can simply use this http://www.rctoys.com/rc-products/GWS-GWFSM002A-ROUND.html
directly connected to RC transmitter and all buttons pressed on RC will be sent directly to USB port, you'll have a virtual COM port and you can read all signals

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into these various options.